# Merging, droping and combining rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

My original formula for merging two dataframes looks like this

```
GES1 = pd.merge(db1, db2, on = 'KO-STA', how = 'left')
```

db1 looks like

```
    ,EID_STAVBA,ST_STAVBE,PLIN,LETO_IZGRA,LETO_OBNOV,LETO_OBNO0,BRUTO_TLOR,EID_OBCINA,SIFKO,EID_DEL_STAVBE,VRSTA_DEJANSKE_RABE_DEL_ST_ID,LETO_OBNOVE_INSTALACIJ,LETO_OBNOVE_OKEN,POVRSINA,ST_DELA_STAVBE,VRSTA_STANOVANJA_ID,UPORABNA_POVRSINA,KO-STA,EID_PARCEL,KO_ID,ST_PARCELE,KO-PAR
0,100200000250868938,4645,0.0,1980.0,,,,110200000110277170,1722,100200000250868958,1,,,37.8,1,,37.8,1722-4645,100100000210682339,1722,903,1722-903
```

db2

```
    ,KO-STA,STA-PAR,KO-PAR,Ukrep_Opis,Ukrep_Kolicina,Ukrep_Enota,UkrepES_Fasada,UkrepES_Streha,UkrepES_Okna,UkrepES_TC,UkrepES_TC_tip,UkrepES_Biomasa,UkrepES_Biomasa_tip,UkrepES_Prezracevanje,UkrepES_PV,UkrepES_SSE
0,1722-4645,0.0,1722-903,Zamenjava oken,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2022.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,1722-4645,0.0,1722-903,TI fasade,0.0,0.0,2022.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,1722-4645,0.0,1722-903,SSE,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2022.0
3,1722-4645,0.0,1722-903,PV,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2022.0,0.0
```

The output looks like this

```
               EID_STAVBA  ST_STAVBE  ...  UkrepES_PV  UkrepES_SSE
0  100200000250868938       4645  ...         0.0          0.0
1  100200000250868938       4645  ...         0.0       2022.0
2  100200000250868938       4645  ...         0.0          0.0
3  100200000250868938       4645  ...      2022.0          0.0
```

In between are 10 identical colums for all rows. The main id is `EID_STAVBA`

How can I rewrite formula so all data for `EID_STAVBA` would be presented in 1 row, e.g.

```
,EID_STAVBA,ST_STAVBE,PLIN,LETO_IZGRA,LETO_OBNOV,LETO_OBNO0,BRUTO_TLOR,EID_OBCINA,SIFKO,EID_DEL_STAVBE,VRSTA_DEJANSKE_RABE_DEL_ST_ID,LETO_OBNOVE_INSTALACIJ,LETO_OBNOVE_OKEN,POVRSINA,ST_DELA_STAVBE,VRSTA_STANOVANJA_ID,UPORABNA_POVRSINA,KO-STA,EID_PARCEL,KO_ID,ST_PARCELE,index,STA-PAR,KO-PAR,Ukrep_Opis,Ukrep_Kolicina,Ukrep_Enota,UkrepES_Fasada,UkrepES_Streha,UkrepES_Okna,UkrepES_TC,UkrepES_TC_tip,UkrepES_Biomasa,UkrepES_Biomasa_tip,UkrepES_Prezracevanje,UkrepES_PV,UkrepES_SSE
0,100200000250868938,4645,0.0,1980.0,,,,110200000110277170,1722,100200000250868958,1,,,37.8,1,,37.8,1722-4645,100100000210682339,1722,903,0,0.0,1722-903,Zamenjava oken,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2022.0,0.0,2022.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2022.0,2022.0
```

?

Do i have to use `groupby`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of `db1` and `db2` and the exact expected output. There are several ways to achieve what you want, but the best method will depend on your exact data

Comment: Both db added. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: You forgot to provide the exact matching expected output ;)

Comment: Indeed. Hope that helps now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use 'groupby'. The groupby function allows you to group the rows based on a specific column (in this case, EID_STAVBA) and then aggregate the values within each group to get a single row for each unique value of EID_STAVBA.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your original dataframes
db1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'EID_STAVBA': ['100200000250868938'],
    'ST_STAVBE': [4645],
    'PLIN': [0.0],
    'LETO_IZGRA': [1980.0],
    'LETO_OBNOV': [None],
    'LETO_OBNO0': [None],
    'BRUTO_TLOR': [None],
    'EID_OBCINA': [None],
    'SIFKO': [110200000110277170],
    'EID_DEL_STAVBE': [1722],
    'VRSTA_DEJANSKE_RABE_DEL_ST_ID': [100200000250868958],
    'LETO_OBNOVE_INSTALACIJ': [1],
    'LETO_OBNOVE_OKEN': [None],
    'POVRSINA': [37.8],
    'ST_DELA_STAVBE': [1],
    'VRSTA_STANOVANJA_ID': [None],
    'UPORABNA_POVRSINA': [37.8],
    'KO-STA': ['1722-4645'],
    'EID_PARCEL': [100100000210682339],
    'KO_ID': [1722],
    'ST_PARCELE': [903],
    'KO-PAR': ['1722-903'],
})

db2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'KO-STA': ['1722-4645', '1722-4645', '1722-4645', '1722-4645'],
    'STA-PAR': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'KO-PAR': ['1722-903', '1722-903', '1722-903', '1722-903'],
    'Ukrep_Opis': ['Zamenjava oken', 'TI fasade', 'SSE', 'PV'],
    'Ukrep_Kolicina': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'Ukrep_Enota': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_Fasada': [0.0, 2022.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_Streha': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_Okna': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_TC': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_TC_tip': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_Biomasa': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_Biomasa_tip': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_Prezracevanje': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'UkrepES_PV': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2022.0],
    'UkrepES_SSE': [0.0, 0.0, 2022.0, 0.0],
})

# Merge the dataframes using the 'KO-STA' column
GES1 = pd.merge(db1, db2, on='KO-STA', how='left')

# Group by 'EID_STAVBA' and aggregate the columns using sum() (you can also use other aggregation functions if needed)
GES1 = GES1.groupby('EID_STAVBA', as_index=False).sum()

# Since you have multiple columns with the same values for each group, you may want to drop the duplicate columns
GES1 = GES1.loc[:, ~GES1.columns.duplicated()]

print(GES1)  # [1 rows x 27 columns]
print(GES1.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This approach won't handle the non-grouping string columns properly (and the use of `sum` will be inefficient on large datasets)

Answer (score 1):

The exact logic is unclear, but it looks like you need to condense the values of `db2` by keeping the first non-NaN values:

```
GES1 = pd.merge(db1,
                db2.replace(0, np.nan)
                   .groupby('KO-STA', as_index=False).first(),
                on=['KO-STA', 'KO-PAR'], how='left'
               )#.fillna(0) # optional
```

Output:

```
           EID_STAVBA  ST_STAVBE  PLIN  LETO_IZGRA  LETO_OBNOV  LETO_OBNO0  BRUTO_TLOR          EID_OBCINA  SIFKO      EID_DEL_STAVBE  ...  UkrepES_Fasada  UkrepES_Streha  UkrepES_Okna  UkrepES_TC  \
0  100200000250868938       4645   0.0      1980.0         NaN         NaN         NaN  110200000110277170   1722  100200000250868958  ...          2022.0             NaN        2022.0         NaN   

   UkrepES_TC_tip  UkrepES_Biomasa  UkrepES_Biomasa_tip UkrepES_Prezracevanje  UkrepES_PV  UkrepES_SSE  
0             NaN              NaN                  NaN                   NaN      2022.0       2022.0  

[1 rows x 36 columns]
```